# Java: RMI issue

Tags: java, tcp, rmi

Hi im trying to connect a client-server application in Java with RMI, in the client i have this

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Registry registro = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.19",1099);
        System.out.println("Cliente esta Corriendo");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    ClienteERI consumir = new ClienteERI();
    consumir.sumaRemota(2, 3);
}
```

and in the server i have this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        Registry registro = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1091);
        registro.rebind("servidor", new ServidorERI());
        System.out.println("Servidor esta corriendo");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

but in the client i have this exception

java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

and in the client  i have the server address correctly (i have check the server addres for a houndred times)

please som

Comment: could be a firewall issue

Comment: Why is the registry unused in the client?

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in trying to check the address a hundred times. The error IS there.

client:

> LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.19",**1099**);

server:

> LocateRegistry.createRegistry(**1091**);

These ports need to match.

Comment: Also, while it's not in any way related to your problem so I did not put that in the answer - I'd recommend using english nomenclature for all non business-specific names. If nothing else, it will make your future questions easier to read.